# How do you uninstall a ClickOnce application that doesn't appear in Add/Remove Programs?

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I'm getting the following error when I try to install one of my ClickOnce applications:

> An application for this deployment is
>   already installed with a different
>   application identity.

I understand this is because I have used the same Application Identity but moved the deployment URL. I'd like to just uninstall the existing ClickOnce application and install from the new deployment location, however the existing application does not show in Add/Remove Programs.

How can I remove the existing ClickOnce application so that it will let me install from the new location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Failing to find another alternative you can try the [mage tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx) with the `-cc` switch. Be advised that this clears the downloaded application cache of **all** online-only applications.

Comment: This was the only ClickOnce app on this machine so the -cc option worked like a charm. Thank you! I would still like to know how to do this with more precision in the future though since nuking everything isn't always an acceptable option :\